# Deleting a user account on the PlayStation 3

Tags: ps3

My son is giving away his PS3.

If he deletes himself as a user on the PS3, will this affect his PS4 account or his PSN account? He has one PSN account which he used on both devices. He does not want to give it away with his personal info on it, and accidentally allow access to his PSN account.

Answer (score 1):

If he is concerned about the data, he can do a restore on the PS3. It will wipe all data and it will be like the device is out of box. The new owner will have to set up a new account on the device for their purposes.

The option is available through the Settings -> System Settings -> Restore PS3.

Comment: This is the best thing to do. To answer the question Shanon is also asking, no it will not affect his PS4 account. You are always able to delete and add accounts to and from Playstation consoles.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting an account on a PlayStation 3 does not directly affect your PSN account; your son's PlayStation 4 account will still work exactly as it did, before.

There is one caveat; if your PlayStation 3 is offline, and you have any account data that still needs to be uploaded to the PlayStation Network (such as data pertaining to trophies), this will naturally be lost.